# How to start a separate thread from a sockets.io triggered thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, socket.io, settimeout

Ok, so I am developing a multiplayer game using:
Node.js, Sockets.io & Redis

Anyway players are able to create a game, then start a game, now the game logic needs to be updated about once every 10 seconds, so this is done via calling a method, that will call itself each x seconds via setTimeout.

My concern is, that when a connected client connects, creates a game (starts the setTimeout cycle) and then disconnects, this will stop any setTimeout's, therefore killing the game for all other players. Even if the setTimeout keeps being fired when a user has disconnected, I would still like to ideally run this seperately to a users socket.io connection.

Is there a simple way to start a seperate process/thread in node.js? (from a connected socket.io connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your purposes, maybe. For instance there's this:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

if that's not it, you might want to look at node fibers

Comment: So whats the difference between fibers and child processes? and also I have found that the timeout method actually still works after a user disconnects their websocket connection, should I just keep it this way? or is there a reason not too?

Comment: Fibers brings thread-like functionality to Node aka yield() etc.
Child processes are sub-processes (not necessarily node, but could be node) that you can run in parallel with node